# EventGuest getName() method not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I just started coding with Google Apps Script.

I tried to write a simple program to pull in events from my calendar and email all the guests in these events.

I have run into 2 problems:

1. the getName() method returns the guest's email address and not name, even though the name is defined in my Google contacts. (Also, if no name is defined, according to the documentation, it would return null).
2. I can't seem to use the getCalendarsByName method. getCalendarByID is working correctly, but the getCalendarsByName method doesn't return the calendar wanted. I've also tried getOwnedCalendarsByName, but that doesn't work either.

Would appreciate any help from anyone.

**Update at 7/1 3.30pm**: Thanks to @Serge insas, the second problem has been solved.
However, the first problem remains. Here's the code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Test Calendar');
    Logger.log(calendar[0].getName());

    var today = new Date(); // get today's date
    Logger.log(today.toLocaleString());
    var endDate = new Date(); 
    endDate.setDate(today.getDate() +7); // set nextWeek's date to 7 days from today
    Logger.log(endDate.toLocaleString());

    var testEvents = calendar[0].getEvents(today, endDate);
    Logger.log(testEvents[0].getTitle());
    var guests = testEvents[0].getGuestList();
    Logger.log(guests[0].getName());
}
```

Here is the Log output:

```
Test Calendar
July 1, 2012 3:27:58 PM EDT
July 8, 2012 3:27:58 PM EDT
Test Event 1
duytri.nguyen07@gmail.com
```

The last line is my email other email address, even though it has been named in my contacts.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getCalendarsByName()` returns an array (that's why there is an 's' on Calendars), did you take this into account in your code by adding [0] behind it (assuming you have only one Cal with this name or that you want its first occurrence) ?

It would be easier to help you if you provide some code you are using.

(Concerning the guestName, same comment : please provide the code you are using.)

EDIT : thanks for the code.  It seems you're right, *it looks like an issue ;-/*

since the guest must be in the contact list to be able to get his name I guess you could use the contact service to get the guest name... as a workaround... I'll try and let you know...

This should work but - I don't know why - it hangs without any result... maybe you could give it a try ?

```
var testEvents = calendar[0].getEvents(today, endDate);
Logger.log(testEvents[0].getTitle());
var guests = testEvents[0].getGuestList();
var guestmail = guests[0].getEmail();
Logger.log(guestmail);
var contact = ContactsApp.getContact(guestmail);
var name = contact.getFullName();
Logger.log(guestmail+'   '+name);
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right, adding [0] did solve the problem for the calendar issue. However, the other question remain.

I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Hey I just tried this method and `name` is just a blank variable for me.

Comment: You could have a look at other methods [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_contact), Contact doesn't work at all for me ;-/

Answer (score 0):

`ContactsApp` is tricky, it can only search in Contacts of user running script, not in global one. In administrator account still havn't access to global contact list.